# Output hash in a table-like format

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to output my hashes to a table. The data have an array called `students`, which has hashes with keys `"first_name"`, `"last_name"`, and `"grade_level"`.

This is the code I have.

```
students = []

# Dummy Inputs.
students = [
  {
      "first_name" => "Bob",
      "last_name" => "Builder",
      "grade_level" => 4
      },
  {
      "first_name" => "Test",
      "last_name" => "Buida",
      "grade_level" => 3
      },
  {
      "first_name" => "Senior",
      "last_name" => "June",
      "grade_level" => 5
      },
  {
      "first_name" => "John",
      "last_name" => "Smith",
      "grade_level" => 2
      },
  {
      "first_name" => "Me",
      "last_name" => "Developer",
      "grade_level" => 11
      }]

...

puts "\n--------------- \n" +
          "| CLASS ROSTER \n" +
          "--------------- \n"  # Felt lazy to add them individual put
    puts "First Name    Last Name    Grade Level\n"

    students.each do |student|
      puts "#{student["first_name"]}        #{student["last_name"]}     #{student["grade_level"]}"
```

I used tab to set the column. Sometimes, it glitches like below.

[image: sample output]

Is there any way to make this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One probably should make use of [`String#ljust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-ljust) and [`String#rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-rjust) helpers here.

First of all, let’s prepare the output:

```
FIELD_SIZE = 20
roster =
  students.map do |s|
    s.values.map do |f|
      f.to_s.ljust(FIELD_SIZE) # 1 row
    end.join('   ')            # join columns with spaces
  end.join($/)                 # join rows with OS-dependent CR/LF
titles =
  ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Grade Level'].map do |t|
    t.to_s.ljust(FIELD_SIZE)
  end.join(' | ')              # join with bars
```

Now you can print it:

```
puts titles, roster
```

Here is the output:

```
First Name           | Last Name            | Grade Level         
Bob                    Builder                4                   
Test                   Buida                  3                   
Senior                 June                   5                   
John                   Smith                  2                   
Me                     Developer              11
```

Feel free to change the joiners and field size to see how it works.

Comment: It worked! However before I accept it as an answer, I have few questions for your variables. You're looping through `student` to get `|f|`. What is `f` gives in terms of a value? Also, what does `FIELD_SIZE` do? Thanks

Comment: `f` states for `field`. Do `puts f.inspect` in the inner loop and you’ll see what it is. `FIELD_SIZE` is the adjustment size (the column width.)