# Ruby: What does is mean by end.join()?

Tags: ruby, loops

Few weeks ago, I asked a question how to output hash

> [Output hash in a table-like format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678790/output-hash-in-a-table-like-format)

and thanks to the awesome community, I've got the response.

```
roster =
  students.map do |s|
    s.values.map do |f|
      f.to_s.ljust(FIELD_SIZE) # 1 row
    end.join('   ')            # join columns with spaces
  end.join($/)                 # join rows with OS-dependent CR/LF
```

It worked for the project, but weeks later, when I was revisiting the code, I realized there were loop in the variable and it had `end.join()`.

What does it mean by `end.join()` **and also** what is `roster`? Is it string? array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I literally know this code in the face, I’d take the responsibility to answer.

> 2. what is `roster`? Is it string? array?

You are basically wasting time posting this kind of questions on SO. Open any ruby [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), e.g. standard `irb` and type:

```
irb|1 ▶ :foo.class
#⇒ Symbol
irb|2 ▶ "foo".class
#⇒ String
irb|3 ▶ roster.class
#⇒ String
```

That is how one might get the immediate answer to the question “what type is this variable.”

> 1. What does it mean by `end.join()`

This is method chaining. Methods in ruby might take zero arguments, some arguments *and also* some arguments *and a block*. The latter might be denoted by curly brackets:

```
#              ⇓            ⇓  HERE
[1, 2, 3].each { |e| puts e }
```

or by `do`-`end`:

```
#              ⇓⇓            ⇓⇓⇓  HERE
[1, 2, 3].each do |e| puts e end
```

There is some subtle difference between these notations, but it’s currently irrelevant to the subject.

So far so good, methods might be chained. That basically means that the latter method is being called on *the result* of the former one:

```
#                           ⇓  HERE
[1, 2, 3].map { |e| e ** e }.each { |e| puts e }
```

this is exactly the same as:

```
intermediate_result = [1, 2, 3].map { |e| e ** e }
intermediate_result.each { |e| puts e }
```

As well, methods might be chained while using `do`-`end` notation.

And, finally, ruby allows additional spaces [almost] anywhere in the code to improve code readability:

```
#                              ⇓  HERE
[1, 2, 3].map do |e| e ** e end.each do |e| puts e end
```

or

```
[1, 2, 3].map do |e|
  e ** e
end.each do |e|
  puts e
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this expression _"Since I literally know this code in the face"_.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby that is a very common practice to chain methods so its just calling the `join` method on the result of that block,

`students.map` returns an array and `join` is used to combine those array elements together using the specified parameter, it could be a comma, any character or new line as `\n`